# Magento 1.9 How to create custom magento object

Tags: magento-1.9

How create custom magento object?
I climbed the entire Internet and can not find the answer
I want to stick my data into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 1 :

```
$object = new Varien_Object();
```

Magento 2 :

```
$object = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
```

Comment: I used this code $object = new Varien_Object(); but how to cram data inside?

Comment: Try : `$object->setData($yourData);`